# How can I merge two array of objects with two different sizes by using key, value pair to merge them into one array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

I have two array of objects that looks this in JSON format:

```
   {
  "Arr1":
   [
    { "_id": "firstSub1", "count": 1, "price": 4 },
    { "_id": "firstSub2", "count": 2, "price": 7 },
    { "_id": "firstSub3", "count": 3, "price": 1 }
    { "_id": "firstSub4", "count": 4, "price": 1 }
   ],

    "Arr2":
     [
      { "name": "firstSub1", "date": 05 / 20 / 1998, "type": sometype1 },
      { "name": "firstSub2"  "date": 12 / 22 / 2011, "type": sometype2 },
      { "name": "firstSub3", "date": 09 / 23 / 2004, "type": sometype3 }
      { "name": "firstSub9", "date": 09 / 23 / 2004, "type": sometype9 }
    ]
//Desired Output
    "finalArray":
     [
      { "name": "firstSub1", "date": 05 / 20 / 1998, "type": sometype1, "count": 1, "price": 4 },  
      { "name": "firstSub2"  "date": 12 / 22 / 2011, "type": sometype2, "count": 2, "price": 7 },
      { "name": "firstSub3", "date": 09 / 23 / 2004, "type": sometype3, "count": 3, "price": 1 },
      { "name": "firstSub9", "date": 09 / 23 / 2004, "type": sometype9 },
      { "_id": "firstSub4", "count": 4, "price": 1 }
          ]   

}
```

I need to compare `_id` in the first array and see if there is a match with `name` in the Arr2 and match them if `_id === name`.

I have tried using lodash and its undescores, and mapping functions like this:

```
  mergeArray() {
    .... //pulling data

    let Arr1 = data['Arr1Data'];
    let Arr2 = data['Arr2Data'];

    let finalArray = Arr2.map((e, _) =>
      (_ = Arr1.find((q) => e.name === q._id)) ?
        { ...e, ..._ } : e)
    console.log(finalArray)
  }
```

All of the data from Arr2 is coming back and merging with only half of the data Arr1  my data is not coming back with the desired output...how can i map these two arrays and have a union and intersection?

Comment: How about merge the arrays first, then use .map function with your custom comparisons to order a new array?

Comment: How? I already tried that.. and I get undefined when i try to call e.name

Comment: `looks this in JSON format:`   When posting questions with example data, try and make it valid, it helps others help you.

Answer (score 2):

Using vanilla Js, you can get an array of unique `_id` and `name` from both arrays, loop throught it and join the object from both arrays that matches the current `id` in the iteration :

Deduped array of `id`s and `name`s :

```
const ids = [...new Set([...Arr1.map(e => e._id), ...Arr2.map(e => e.name)])];
```

Loop to join elements from both arrays :

```
const result = ids.map(e => ({
  ...Arr1.find(o => o._id === e),
  ...Arr2.find(o => o.name === e)
}))
```

```js
const Arr1 = [{"_id": "firstSub1","count": 1,"price": 4},{"_id": "firstSub2","count": 2,"price": 7},{"_id": "firstSub3","count": 3,  "price": 1}, {"_id": "firstSub4","count": 4,"price": 1}];

const Arr2 = [{"name": "firstSub1","date": "05 / 20 / 1998","type": "sometype1"}, {"name": "firstSub2","date": "12 / 22 / 2011","type": "sometype2"}, {"name": "firstSub3","date": "09 / 23 / 2004","type": "sometype3"}, {"name": "firstSub9","date": "09 / 23 / 2004","type": "sometype9"}];

const ids = [...new Set([...Arr1.map(e => e._id), ...Arr2.map(e => e.name)])];

const result = ids.map(e => ({
  ...Arr2.find(o => o.name === e),
  ...Arr1.find(o => o._id === e)
}))
console.log(result)
```

EDIT :
You can tweak the returned object in `.map()` to remove properties ( like `_id`) :

```js
const Arr1 = [{"_id": "firstSub1","count": 1,"price": 4},{"_id": "firstSub2","count": 2,"price": 7},{"_id": "firstSub3","count": 3,  "price": 1}, {"_id": "firstSub4","count": 4,"price": 1}];

const Arr2 = [{"name": "firstSub1","date": "05 / 20 / 1998","type": "sometype1"}, {"name": "firstSub2","date": "12 / 22 / 2011","type": "sometype2"}, {"name": "firstSub3","date": "09 / 23 / 2004","type": "sometype3"}, {"name": "firstSub9","date": "09 / 23 / 2004","type": "sometype9"}];

const ids = [...new Set([...Arr1.map(e => e._id), ...Arr2.map(e => e.name)])];

const result = ids.map(e => {
  const obj = {
    ...Arr2.find(o => o.name === e),
    ...Arr1.find(o => o._id === e)
  }
  
  if(obj.name && obj._id) delete obj._id;
  
  return obj;
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Great anser Taki. Just one tweak they want _id removed. But awesome nonetheless.

Comment: Nice. what if the desired finalArray is :
 
` 

 "finalArray":
  [
      { "name": "firstSub1", "date": 05 / 20 / 1998, "type": sometype1, "count": 1, "price": 4 },  
      { "name": "firstSub2"  "date": 12 / 22 / 2011, "type": sometype2, "count": 2, "price": 7 },
      { "name": "firstSub3", "date": 09 / 23 / 2004, "type": sometype3, "count": 3, "price": 1 }, 

`

how would the delete function be used on the arrays that has no match

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash's `_.flow()` to create a function that combines the arrays, groups them by `name` or `_id` (whatever is found on the object). If the a group contains more than 1 item, it's merged to a single object, and the `_id` property is omitted.

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, concat, groupBy, map, merge, has, head, omit } = _

const fn = flow(
  concat, // combine to a single array
  pr(groupBy, o => o.name || o._id), // group by the value of name or _id
  pr(map, o => o.length === 1 ? head(o) : _.omit( // if a group contains 2 items merge them, and remove _id
    merge({}, ...o),
    '_id'
  )),
)

const Arr1 = [{"_id": "firstSub1","count": 1,"price": 4},{"_id": "firstSub2","count": 2,"price": 7},{"_id": "firstSub3","count": 3,  "price": 1}, {"_id": "firstSub4","count": 4,"price": 1}]

const Arr2 = [{"name": "firstSub1","date": "05 / 20 / 1998","type": "sometype1"}, {"name": "firstSub2","date": "12 / 22 / 2011","type": "sometype2"}, {"name": "firstSub3","date": "09 / 23 / 2004","type": "sometype3"}, {"name": "firstSub9","date": "09 / 23 / 2004","type": "sometype9"}]

const result = fn(Arr2, Arr1)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Credit should be given to this answer. I'm using it also to merge duplications in a single array. `fn(Arr1)` works even with one argument.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) starting with an `accumulator` equal to a copy of `Arr2` (`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Arr2))`) so we don't mutate the original array `Arr2`. Now, while iterating over `Arr1`, if we found a match then we add the related properties using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to the associated object on the `accumulator`, otherwise we put the entire object on the `accumulator`:

```js
const Arr1 = [
    {"_id": "firstSub1", "count": 1, "price": 4},
    {"_id": "firstSub2", "count": 2, "price": 7},
    {"_id": "firstSub3", "count": 3, "price": 1},
    {"_id": "firstSub4", "count": 4, "price": 1}
];

const Arr2 = [
    {"name": "firstSub1", "date": "05/20/1998", "type": "sometype1"},
    {"name": "firstSub2",  "date": "12/22/2011", "type": "sometype2"},
    {"name": "firstSub3", "date": "09/23/2004", "type": "sometype3"},
    {"name": "firstSub9", "date": "09/23/2004", "type": "sometype9"}
];

let res = Arr1.reduce((acc, {_id, count, price}) =>
{
    let fIdx = acc.findIndex(({name}) => name === _id);

    if (fIdx >= 0)
        Object.assign(acc[fIdx], {count, price});
    else
        acc.push({_id, count, price});
        
    return acc;
}, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Arr2)));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by `name` and compare the `i + 1` index name to validate if the `i + 1` index and the `i` index should be merged or if the object doesn't have a pair for merging.

For example, sorting by `name` means that the next object/index will be the pair.

```
[{name: "firstSub1", count: 1}, {name: "firstSub1", date: "dd / mm / yyyy"}] // Pair found
```

or

```
[{name: "firstSub1", count: 1}, {name: "firstSub2", count: 1}] // There is no a pair
```

***This is assuming there is max one pair***

```js
let obj = {  "Arr1": [{      "_id": "firstSub1",      "count": 1,      "price": 4    },    {      "_id": "firstSub2",      "count": 2,      "price": 7    },    {      "_id": "firstSub3",      "count": 3,      "price": 1    },    {      "_id": "firstSub4",      "count": 4,      "price": 1    }  ],  "Arr2": [{      "name": "firstSub1",      "date": "05 / 20 / 1998",      "type": "sometype1"    },    {      "name": "firstSub2",      "date": "12 / 22 / 2011",      "type": "sometype2"    },    {      "name": "firstSub3",      "date": "09 / 23 / 2004",      "type": "sometype3"    },    {      "name": "firstSub9",      "date": "09 / 23 / 2004",      "type": "sometype9"    }  ]};

// All objects in one array.
let merge = [...obj.Arr2, 
             // The map is to change _id by name, this is used later.
             ...obj.Arr1.map(({_id, count, price}) => ({name: _id, count, price}))]
                  .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

// This approach doesn't mutate the source objects.
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < merge.length;) {
  if (merge[i + 1] && merge[i + 1].name === merge[i].name) {
    result.push(Object.assign(Object.create(null), merge[i], merge[i + 1]));
    i++;
  } else result.push(merge[i]);
  i++;
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```